# Ajax page load in div halts browser even if it is async?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do async page open inside div with $.ajax but i am still having about 3sec delay after clicking link and that time page is jammed. Happens at least chrome and sasfari. Where am i going wrong way..?

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    async: true
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Button").click(function(evt) {
        $('#change').html('<p><img src="ajax-loader.gif" width="15" height="15" /></p>');
        $.ajax({
            url: "reg.php",
            cache: false
        }).done(function( html ) {
            $("#change").html(html);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use `async:true` in `$.ajax` also why you are doing it separately?

Comment: Moreover, it's the default.

Comment: Your browser would not be locked up with this code.

Comment: @Jarno Have you checked your console for errors?

Answer (score 1):

No, asynchronous ajax requests like that don't hold up the browser. The problem is elsewhere, in code you haven't shown. The code you've shown will correctly do an async request.

Speculating on possible issues with what we can't see:

1. If the link has an `href`, you're not cancelling the default action, so it could be loading the page. You can prevent the default by calling `evt.preventDefault()` within your click handler, or by doing `return false;` at the end of it (which does that and also stops propagation).
2. If you have other code elsewhere setting `async: false` as the default, perhaps your `ajaxSetup` changing it back isn't getting called.

Comment: It works very fast with firefox but jamms with safari and chrome. Firebug does not see any problems in this. Bit lost here....

Comment: @Jarno: Given that it works on Firefox, Firebug isn't going to be much use to you. :-) Chrome has excellent dev tools, press F12.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP sessions then the script will halt the browser until reg.php is completely finished.

In reg.php you will need to add this somewhere:

```
session_write_close();
```

This will allow you to read the session data but not write to it.

This is the case because you would probably never want two ASYNC scripts trying to write to the session at the same exact time.

Comment: PHP cannot magically reach out to the browser to hold up its processing JavaScript on the page. It could serialize *other* requests to PHP, but not hold up JavaScript on the page *already* in the browser.

Comment: session_write_close(); I think this made it about 1/2 sec faster but still jammed. Yes i am using session.

Comment: Let me elaborate. I have an SQL query which can take between 10-60 seconds to finish for which I provide a loading GIF. If I do not close the session then I experience a lockup when trying to navigate to a different page. Once I added session_write_close(); then my lockup went away. Reference: http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/

Comment: Yes, i added session_write_close(); to my php. No change. Also firefox works in 200ms all the time without locking.

Comment: *"...I experience a lockup when trying to navigate to a different page..."* Right. Because the browser is trying to talk to the server again, *synchronously*, because that's how navigation works, and PHP is able to make it wait (because it's blocking, waiting for a reasponse from the server). Totally different from asynchronous ajax.

Comment: Chrome dev tools says it takes 2.65s to execute jquery-1.101.js file. Php goes through in 1.36 sec.

Comment: T.J. Crowder; why locking is depending on browser cause php is runned on server side?

Comment: Also when js. file is holding 2.65.sec it is receiving.

Comment: Thanks to everyone! Finally solved this after understanding the base problem! 5am late coding works every time! :)